# Select data from node object

Tags: node.js, object, pagination

I want to show email from object in node.

This is my route

```
// View users
router.get("/show", function (req, res, next) {

    var query = {};
    var options = {};

    User.paginate(query, options).then(function (result) {
        return res.render("../modules/users/views/userList", {
            layout: 'cmsLayout',
            users: result.docs,
            page: parseInt(result.page),
            pages: parseInt(result.pages)
        });
    });
});
```

and my handlebars

```
    <h1>{{users}}</h1> // WORK
    { created: 2018-11-25T20:33:19.531Z, _id: 5bfb070fa18eb649e0b5ea97, firstname: 'Jxxxx', lastname: 'xxxx', email: 'xxxxx', password: 'xxxxxx', ipadress: '::1', provider: 'local', status: '1', secretToken: 'xxxxxx', __v: 0 }

    <h1>{{users.email}}</h1> // WONT WORK
```

I know its really stupid question but i cant figure out how to show only email or only firstname...

Comment: How did you get the timestamp? It seems confusing with all these colons

Comment: @gkont Well it need to be edited of course. But this is my way. created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using [mongoose](/questions/tagged/mongoose) with [mongoose-paginate](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate). According to the docs, the parameter passed to **paginate**'s callback (ie. `result`) [**should** be an array](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate#modelpaginatequery-options-callback). This can be confirmed by checking the return value of `typeof result.docs`. You might want to do this in your handlebars template:

```
{{#each users}}
  <h1>{{this.email}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```